# How to run SonarQube analysis during each gradle build?

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, static-analysis

Is it possible to run sonarqube analysis after each gradle build?
I do have running sonarqube when typing *gradle sonarqube* but I when typing *gradle build* in console analysis do not perform.

```
plugins {
   .

   .

    id "org.sonarqube" version "3.0"
}
```

What should I add to build.gradle to make it run?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember properly, it's something like `build.finalizedBy(sonarqube)`.